# JDeveloper ABCS problem

Tags: wsdl, soapui, jdeveloper, bpel, oracle-soa

So I have created an ABCS BPEL process in JDeveloper, it compiles without any errors. I'm trying to test it via soapUI but I am getting the following error:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault>
         <faultcode>env:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>oracle.fabric.common.FabricInvocationException: Unable to access the following endpoint(s): http://REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_HOST_AND_PORT/ENVIRONMENT_NAME/com-telekom-xmlns-ng-EnterpriseServices-Core-TroubleTicket-V1-services-CommunicationsTroubleTicketEBS.soap2jms/1.0</faultstring>
         <faultactor/>
         <detail>
            <exception>Unable to access the following endpoint(s): http://REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_HOST_AND_PORT/ENVIRONMENT_NAME/com-telekom-xmlns-ng-EnterpriseServices-Core-TroubleTicket-V1-services-CommunicationsTroubleTicketEBS.soap2jms/1.0</exception>
         </detail>
      </env:Fault>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Which is strange because in my config plan I have added the following, replacing the REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_HOST_AND_PORT/ENVIRONMENT_NAME part with an actual address:

```
   <wsdlAndSchema name="CommunicationsTroubleTicketEBSResponse.wsdl|CommunicationsTroubleTicketEBS.wsdl">
      <searchReplace>
        <search>http://REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_HOST_AND_PORT/ENVIRONMENT_NAME/com-telekom-xmlns-ng-EnterpriseServices-Core-TroubleTicket-V1-services-CommunicationsTroubleTicketEBSResponse.soap2jms/1.0</search>
        <replace>http://soainta52:8001/soa-infra/services/ServiceRequestsStubs/TTMCreateTroubleTicketStub/TTMCreateTroubleTicketStub_ep</replace>
      </searchReplace>
      <searchReplace>
        <search>http://REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_HOST_AND_PORT/ENVIRONMENT_NAME/com-telekom-xmlns-ng-EnterpriseServices-Core-TroubleTicket-V1-services-CommunicationsTroubleTicketEBS.soap2jms/1.0</search>
        <replace>http://soainta52:8001/soa-infra/services/ServiceRequestsStubs/TTMCreateTroubleTicketStub/TTMCreateTroubleTicketStub_ep</replace>
      </searchReplace>
   </wsdlAndSchema>
```

Answer (score 1):

When deploying your BPEL you have to select the deployment plan.

Are you make this deployment from JDeveloper or from a the enterprise manager console?